# Amazon S3 CLI command how to show the modification/update date witht the aws s3 command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The

```
aws s3 ls
```

returned the timestamp the creation of the bucket files, the files size and the file name of the files.

Is there a way to list the timestamp of the update or modification rather than the date of the creation? I tried this one https://www.codingace.com/cloud-computing/get-last-modified-object-from-s3-using-aws-cli and didn't work.

Comment: You can't modify or update S3 objects. You can only replace them.

Comment: @jarmod The replacement date then.

Comment: That is what's shown by `aws s3 ls` afaik. Test it by uploading an object, run `aws s3 ls`, then wait a minute and test again (upload then list).

Comment: The only date/time value S3 objects have is the [Last-Modified](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html#API_HeadObject_ResponseSyntax) field, which is the "creation date of the object".  If you want any other meta-data with the object, you'll need to track it yourself somehow.

Comment: FYI, it's easier to use [`aws s3api list-objects-v2` — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html) if you wish to retrieve a specific field. For example: `aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket MY-BUCKET --prefix PATH-OR-KEY --query 'Contents[].LastModified' --output text`